# How to answer command line prompts in script in docker

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I'm running a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM alexhermstad/arch-pypi2pkgbuild-kolibri
MAINTAINER Alex Hermstad
USER kol
WORKDIR /home/kol/pypi2pkgbuild
CMD ["python", "./pypi2pkgbuild.py", "--pre", "kolibri"]
```

Within pypi2pkgbuild.py, there's a prompt that comes up, which says:

```
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

Is there anyway that I can use docker to automatically press 'n' to skip the installation? I searched for a bit and could not find a solution to this using a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to send it directly to the script

```
CMD ["start.sh"]

#start.sh
echo "N" | python ./pypi2pkgbuild.py --pre kolibri
```

If this is no option, there is a tool called "expect" to handle interactive prompts.

[Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)